# Search a table in jQuery after new rows have been added

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am very bad at Javascript/Jquery. Now that that's out of the way, I need some help with searching a dynamically built table. Here's the problem: on the pageload of my asp site, the repeater is bound, and the table is populated. I can use some sweet javascript function to filter the table, and that works very well. Unfortunately, I also rely on SignalR to get some realtime data into the table (it's a debug logger for another software project). Using SignalR and jQuery, I am able to prepend the new table row at the top and delete the last row so everything stays the same size. **Once a new row is added to the table, though, my Javascript search breaks and is unable to search the newly added rows.** I'm going to assume javascript does some sort of index on the table, but I'm not sure if that's right, and if it is, can I reindex?  Yes, I have linked signalr and jquery up correctly. Thanks!

Below you'll find all the relevant code

HTML/ASP:

```
            <HeaderTemplate>

                <table id="debugTable"  class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr >
                            <th  >Time Stamp</th>
                            <th >Level</th>
                            <th >Logger</th>
                            <th >Message</th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="list">
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <tr >

                    <td class="timestamp"><%#Eval("Time_Stamp")%></td>     
                    <td class="debuglevel" ><%#Eval("Level")%></td>
                    <td class="logger"><%#Eval("Logger")%></td>
                    <td  class="message"><%#Eval("Message")%></td>                 
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        var myChatHub = $.connection.myChatHub;
        myChatHub.client.newMessageReceived = function (time, level, logger, text) {




            $('#debugTable tr:first').after('<tr> <td>' + time + '</td><td class="debuglevel">' + level + '</td><td>' + logger + '</td><td>' + text + '</td> </tr>');



            $('#debugTable tr:last').remove();
}
 });


 $('.search').keyup(function() {
       $.each($(".list").find("tr"), function () {
           if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($('.search').val().toLowerCase()) == -1)
               $(this).hide();
           else
               $(this).show();
       });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked for browser debug errors?

Comment: Yes, nothing being thrown in the 3 different browsers.

Comment: I would start looking into Angular or Knockout

Comment: I'm sure those are great, but seems like taking a knife to a gunfight. I don't really need that much bloat or power for one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you search function is this one right?

`$('.search').keyup(function(){ . . . . })`

evertime you add new ROWS in your TABLE the event needs to be called again, because the jQuery was loaded the old structure of HTML Elements.

So, to prevent a chain events in your page and solve the problem, you need to change your implementation to this:

`function search(){ 
    $('.search').unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function(){ . . . });
}
search();`

And call the function everytime you add new rows in your table:

`search()`;

Cheers,

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Gracias, Sir! Your solution was correct, it was just a silly mistake on my part, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem!**

It turns out every time I was adding a new row to the table, I was adding it to the thead. As a result, the search function was simply skipping those new rows. By simply changing my jquery selector to the following, I was able to add things to the tbody, and not the thead.

```
 $('#debugTable tbody tr:first')
```

As opposed to

```
  $('#debugTable tr:first')
```

A big shoutout to [Cícero Feijó](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3919279/c%C3%ADcero-feij%C3%B3), who helped me with the search function and the event binding/unbinding. I have marked his response as the answer because that is the right way to do this, it was just a small oversight in my code that prevented his solution from working.